# How can I change the url of add new item in sharepoint except sharepoint designer?

Tags: list-form

I created a custom webpart for the newform of a list. So, I need to change the default url of add new item to my configured custom form page instead of default `newform.aspx`. I used SharePoint Designer, but it has some problem, so may I know the procedure to change url rather than the Designer?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the NewForm by setting the `DefaultNewFormUrl` property of the `List` object:

```
using ( var ctx = new ClientContext( url ))
{
    var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle( 'List' );
    list.DefaultNewFormUrl = newFormUrl;

    list.Update();
    ctx.Load( list );
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Make changes as needed.  Not sure if the absolute url is required, or if a relative one can be used.  And you may not need to load the list after the `list.Update()`.

Answer (score 0):

When in designer, go the the list view, and you will see a block that contians your forms.  Click on the form you want as default, and at the top of the ribbon, there will be an option called "Set as Standard".  Click that, and that view will now be your standard view.